# .NET 5: X509Certificate.GetNameInfo Uppercases unicode escape characters

Tags: c#, x509

I've googled this for a couple of hours and couldn't find anything.
So, I've got a certificate which has "ОАО" (russian letters) in its Simple Name for Subject.
I get this value using this code:

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(certificateBytes);
var subjectName = x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, forIssuer: false);
```

On Windows, this code returns 'ОАО' and this gets saved into MS SQL.
But on Linux in Docker container this code returns escaped unicode characters, **but in caps.**
Here they are:

```
\U041E\U0410\U041E
```

Instead of:

```
\u041E\u0410\u041E
```

And this caps is getting saved instead of 'ОАО'. So when I do nothing, it's \U1234 and it's written as-is in database: literally *\U1234*. But when I perform .ToLower()-transformation, this code transforms to \u1234 and is recognized as 'ОАО'.
So I've come up with a hack but I'm not sure it's the right thing to do. Anyway, that does save my text as 'ОАО' in database:

```
var subjectName = Regex.Unescape(x509.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, forIssuer: false).ToLowerInvariant());
```

What do you think? Is this a bug? Why does this method behave this way? Why it '*capses*' unicode escape /u-character?
Is this a correct way to solve the problem?
Can I encounter a situation in which I'll find some unicode case-sensitive characters in which case I can lose the characters or they are case insensitive?

Comment: Is anything wrong with the "U" instead of "u" in this case?

Comment: @AgentFire yeah there is. 
See, the database does not recognize it as valid unicode-characters so it's unreadable.
And I can't in any way decode it back to Russian. Even C# itself uses \u as an escape-character so it can recognize it.
I'm not into encodings so I might be wrong. Either way I'm confused why \U1234 is written as-is but \u1234 is recognized as a character. I presume that \U is invalid escaping. I'll update the question to clarify why the case matters.

Comment: The char array as you present it - "\u1234" - is but a simple string, and I honestly don't quite follow as to **why** your database tries to decode it. What I also don't understand is how you are **getting** that "escaped" string. Surely `x509.GetNameInfo` wouldn't return an escaped string, forcing you to unescape it back.

Comment: Can you share (or identify) a certificate with this issue?  I'm really curious as to how the name is encoded to produce such a result.

Comment: @AgentFire I'm sorry, but maybe ```Regex.Unescape()``` isn't even necessary? 
Well, maybe when I lowercase the output it's already unescaped and is good to be saved and read in russian.
```x509.GetNameInfo``` returns exactly what I wrote: 'U\1234' hence unreadable cryptic text in database.

Comment: @bartonjs umm, I won't share the exact certificate but you can use any public russian certificate. You can visit https://iitrust.ru/downloads/ca/guc2021.crt -- it'll download a certificate for you. There you'll find subject and issuer in russian.
This issue comes up only on **english Linux**. Unfortunately, I'm unable to debug it -- maybe I'll try to log the output to console to make sure that it's what X509Certificate2 returns.
Thank you for your interest. I'd be glad to hear from you about it. I'd be surprised if you get Uppercase unicode characters.

Comment: Weird.  Opened an issue for this at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/59105.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a bug?

Yes it was a bug and has been [fixed in .NET 6 RC2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/59172) (which is yet to be released, but is the next release of .NET 6 previews).

The Linux implementation of this with OpenSSL was inadvertently escaping non-ASCII text.